# Particles System Mesh fills with less particles than expected

Tags: mesh, particles

I'm trying to create a cube with 500 particles in it to represent particulate matter (pm2.5) in the air. This is what I have so far - I have it set to 519 but I'm pretty sure there aren't that many particles in the cube. Any help is appreciated, I'm really stuck.
Thanks in advance [image]

Comment: Did you count the points? I'm pretty sure that's 500+ ;-)

Comment: @quellenform Actually at frame 61 it is 397 ... from what I counted :) if Dead is off.

Comment: @vklidu Oh, really, you actually counted them manually now!? ...I love you! :-)  (sorry fot this stupid comments)

Comment: @quellenform OK, than sorry for my stupid joke. I didn't :) I made them real ... your comment is on place (since OP is guessing too :) )

Answer (score 1):

That's true, because you have set the lifetime to 50. Blender distributes all particles over time. If you want to make sure to have 500, just set frame end to 1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you set 500 particles and *Emission Frame End* 50, there will be 500 particles at frame 50.

Particles are distributed from *frame start* 1 to *frame end* 50 with *Lifetime* of each particle 50 frames ... it means particle Born at frame 1 is Dead at frame 51 and disappears.

Your timeline is set at frame 61 it means some of your particles starting disappear after frame 50.

If you want to see 500 particles after frame 50 you have to set higher **Lifetime** value or enable under *Particle Properties > Render > Extras >* **Dead**

---

To see how many particles is currently in your *Cube* export Cube as **Alembic** (.abc) and import back. It will automatically converts each particle into vertex ... amount easily visible in **Statistics** overlay.

If you have under *Preferences > Interface > Developer Extras* enabled, than you can see numbered vertices in *3D view* if you go to Edit mode and under Overlays > Developers able Indices to see vertices numbered.

[image]

**Geometry nodes**
Can be seen in Spreadsheet ...

[image]
Since vertices are numbered from zero, the last one is number 499.

Or add this nodes to separate specific one ...

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is so helpful

Comment: Great if you found it useful. Sadly I don't know an option to count particles directly. But I just edited my A, so just by "Make Instances Real" you can check highest number of generated objects in Outliner or Statistics and just Undo. Indices in 3Dview confused me  when I spotted vertex numbered 864, than I realised there are particles at the same position [(they are overlapping)](https://imgur.com/JyBaqUl) ... so if specific number matters there was somewhere option to avoid that ... I just cant find it now.